# MediaWiki Memory allocation error

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am getting this error when i click special pages link in MediaWiki

```
Fatal error: Possible integer overflow in memory allocation (2147483648 * 4 + 0) in var/www/mediawiki/includes/User.php on line 2440
```

this is the code

```
if ( !$ignoreHidden && in_array( $oname, $wgHiddenPrefs ) ) {
            return self::getDefaultOption( $oname );
        }
```

Comment: MediaWiki/PHP version? Do you have APC or something similar installed?

Comment: MediaWiki-1.23 and PHP version:5.3.8

Comment: This could be a 32 Bit problem as (2147483648 * 4) = the 32Bit number so see if you can built / update to the 64Bit version if you can

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh Are you using 32bit PHP packages on a 64bit system?  Just a guess, it's hard to tell with just this information.  Is the problem reproducible?  If you install same version of PHP and same version of Mediawiki on another machine, do you have the same problem?  Or, is the problem related to the number of articles in your Mediawiki?  Just stuff I'd ask myself :)

Comment: is php files are written differently for 32bit and 64 bit processors?

Answer (score 2):

It will be difficult to find the origin of the bug, there are plenty of people reporting this bug in various softwares (MediaWiki, Joomla, phpBB, CiviCRM, [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project_talk:Support_desk/Fatal_error:_Possible_integer_overflow_in_memory_allocation), etc.) so it’s likely a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36722) (or an OS bug, or some claim about a CPU bug -- see PHP bug).

From what I understand, people try to recompile PHP, to change the PHP version, to increase the memory, to deactivate PHP extensions, to clear cache, and I guess some of the solutions make the bug disappear but it’s not clear how people solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MediaWiki but there must be somewhere a configuration file.( something ending in '.ini 'perhaps)
User.php for example : is there a coded line named memory_size?

If you find one, change it's value to twice or even more.